# Handling 404 pages(404page components appearing every pages)

Tags: reactjs

```
      <Route path="/shop">
       <Shop> </Shop>
      </Route>

      <Route path="*">
        <NotFound></NotFound>
      </Route>

      <Route path="/review"> 
       <Review> </Review>
      </Route>
```

In NotFound page i have written a error message. And in (shop and review) i'm adding different messages.But all the pages are including the message from not found pages. How to solve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gA5r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/shop">Shop</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/review">Review</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/shop">
            <Shop />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/review">
            <Review />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="*">
            <NotFound />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Shop() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Shop</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>NotFound</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Review() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Review</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[More Detail](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)